# Deploy Jar to remote server from Jenkins Build Job

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I currently have a Jenkins job that does the following successfully:

1: Check for new commits in git repo ✓
2: clone repo ✓
3: Build repo jar with maven ✓
4: scp jar to remote server ✓

The 5th step is to run the jar, I am currently doing something like:

```
nohup ssh user@remotehost "java -jar some.jar" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This works technically, it will run the jar, however the jenkins job is not finishing, I assume it is waiting for an exit code.

What I wish to achieve is, fire a command to a remote server over ssh without waiting for a response or output. I'm not sure if this is possible, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll help, but you can try starting the process in background using `&` (ampersand), so you will detach from the process right after the command has been issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `screen` command:

```
screen -d -m ssh user@remote "java -jar -Dserver.port=9090 ~/jar.jar"
```

From manual:

> -d -m Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

Comment: This worked, I had seen a previous post about screen, but wasn't sure if it would still leave a hanging job and just not show output. It works with the following command
`screen -d -m ssh user@remote  "java -jar -Dserver.port=9090 ~/jar.jar"`

Comment: @ConorThompson glad that it has worked. I've updated the answer to match the correct command.